# How do I set a custom Job Id for a google dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I want to have customised Job Name and Job Id for each google dataflow Job I run. I am to create a customised Job name for the job.

But i am unable to set a customised job id.

I found a `com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.options.DataflowWorkerHarnessOptions` interface which has a method setJobId(String value). But I was unable to use that also create a customized job id.

Is there a way to create a customized Job Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JobId is the Dataflow service's identifier for the job and must be globally unique, so the service does not allow the user to pick one.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to configure jobName instead. In your program, you can set jobName using options.
This also helps in quickly searching related job from the dataflow listing page.
In your DataflowPipelineOptions, there is paramerter to set job

```html
Ex - options.setJobName("MyExtractionJob"+ new Date());
```